# Mobile frame work suggestion

Tags: iphone, android, mobile

I have been asked by my employer to develop an mobile web application which will need to connect to database. I have experience working on C#.net,asp.net,sql server, AJAX and Jquery. I also have experience developing iphone apps using objective C. Can you suggest me a good and reliable mobile frame work which is based on above technologies. I would like the web application  to be compatible with many type of devices(iPhone,Android,BB at least….!!!!).

Thanks in advance…

Answer (score 0):

One of my clients is using jQuery Mobile, and loving it.  Seems to fit your skillset too.
[JQuery Mobile Site](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to make a web application and not a native mobile application - so what do you need a mobile framework for?

Most mobiles can read most web pages nowadays - so use any web application framework you are comfortable with.

Comment: Looks like I confused you. Actually I want to make sure the interface is of mobile app type. Allthough all website open on mobile devices...they are not easy to read or browse.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/)